# C++ declare a priority queue in an else/if?

Tags: c++, declaration, priority-queue

I have two different priority queues that use different comparators.  I would like an if/else with a boolean value to determine which p.q. will be set to a variable (for example, "pq");

For example I have

```
priority_queue<test, vector<test>, CompareTest1> pq;
```

How would I place this in an if/else so if a boolean is flagged pq will be set like...

```
priority_queue<test, vector<test>, CompareTest2> pq;
```

using the different comparator.  Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to do, we can't answer that question. What we can say is that you're looking for an O(1) sort algorithm, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I pretty much have a program that has a boolean passed in to decide which type of priority queue should be used.  I would like to keep the same variable, pq.  I would just like it to be set to the right kind of priority queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done because if you give a different template param the two templates are different types. My suggestion would be to pass a compare functor that has a boolean which is determined by whatever was gonna be in that if statement. For example:

```
struct compare {
    bool b;   
    //set this instead of the if statement and allow the function to do something different
    operator () (const test & lhs, const test & rhs) {
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was the approach I was thinking about taking.

Comment: @Robert no problem, just so you know functors are preferred over function pointers for this type of thing

Comment: I was thinking of two function pointers. Seems this is better for inlining.

Comment: @C.R. correct and the reason `std::sort` is significantly faster than `qsort`

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a priority queue doesn't allow what you're looking for -- the elements are ordered in the priority queue according to their comparator. Creating a priority queue with a different comparator is tantamount to creating a brand new priority queue.